# Add resource argument in loop from list of strings

Tags: terraform, hcl

I'm trying to set up a [Digital Ocean Database Firewall](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/database_firewall), which uses the below syntax:

```
resource "digitalocean_database_firewall" "example-fw" {
  cluster_id = digitalocean_database_cluster.app.id

  rule {
    type  = "ip_addr"
    value = "192.168.1.1"
  }

  rule {
    type  = "ip_addr"
    value = "192.0.2.0"
  }
}
```

I have a variable which is a list of whitelisted IPs that should be added to the firewall, along with the VPC IP block. I first tried to add these using `for_each`:

```
# Postgres firewall (only allow connection inside VPC)
resource "digitalocean_database_firewall" "vpc-fw" {
  cluster_id = digitalocean_database_cluster.app.id

  rule {
    type  = "ip_addr"
    value = digitalocean_vpc.app_vpc.ip_range
  }
}

# Postgres firewall (allow connections from whitelisted IPs)
resource "digitalocean_database_firewall" "whitelisted-fw" {
  for_each = toset(var.db_allowed_ips)

  cluster_id = digitalocean_database_cluster.app.id

  rule {
    type  = "ip_addr"
    value = each.key
  }
}
```

However it seems you can only have one firewall resource per cluster as only the last IP is saved and shows on the dashboard.

I also tried using `for_each` in the `rule` block but this throws an error that it can only appear in module or resource blocks.

I've also tried passing the list to `value` directly, but it only supports strings and not lists.

How can I add a `rule { }` block for each IP in `var.db_allowed_ips` and `digitalocean_vpc.app_vpc.ip_range`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks):

```
resource "digitalocean_database_firewall" "whitelisted-fw" {
  cluster_id = digitalocean_database_cluster.app.id

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = toset(var.db_allowed_ips)

    content {
      type  = "ip_addr"
      value = each.value
    }
  }
}
```

I believe the `for_each` meta-argument at the dynamic block scope accepts values of `list(string)`, but nothing is lost by being safe and using the normal type conversion to `set(string)`.